# How to retrieve all the topics of Kafka after system restart?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to retrieve all the topics that I created before shutting down my system.

However, I realised that the topics I created are no more once I rebooted my system.

I use the following commands:
1. `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

2. `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`
3. `bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
   test`

The 3rd command returns nothing. It seems that the topic I had created is lost.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, your Kafka logs are stored under `/tmp` directory. You need to change that location in the configuration file and set it into a permanent location which does not get wiped on reboot.

Comment: What location do you use?
Is desktop good enough? Also, from where do I change the logs' configuration(s)?

Comment: I have made the following edit:
1. In the config/zookeeper.properties:
Changed `dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper` to `dataDir=/home/aviral/logsDeDev/zookeeper`

Is this okay? Please note that the `/home/aviral/logsDeDev/zookeeper` is a newly created directory of mine.

Comment: I changed the log directory but in vain. I cannot retrieve a single message from the topic after system restart.

Comment: Are the topics there after rebooting your system?

Comment: Issue resolved, the change had to be done in the server.properties file and not the Zookeeper.properties file.

With this done:
1. I can get all the messages in the topic after reboot
2. I cannot get the list of the topics. HOWEVER, once I run the command for a particular topic's messages and then I run the command to list out the topics, I get the topics' list.

Did you get it? Have I explained the issue well?

Comment: What does `bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181` output after reboot?

Comment: Nothing. It is just blank.